# ¿Cómo crear enlace amigable con guion en asp.net core razor pages?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

Hola estaba buscando en la red pero la verdad no encontré como resolver mi pregunta.

Estoy utilizando Asp.net Core 2 con Razor-pages. No tengo mucho en utilizar los mapeos de enlaces. Quiero utilizar guión medio en los controller y también poner una Variable antes de un controller de por ejemplo

```
/pagina-de-algo
/destino-en/paquetes/nombre-de-paquete
```

vi que las paginas.cshtml no pueden utilizar los enlaces con guión medio por lo que utilice el guión bajo y así si entra las paginas

```
/pagina_de_algo
```

Intente modificando mi rute pero al parecer no era así

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "pagina", template: "pagina-de-algo",
                defaults: new { controller = "pagina_de_algo", action = "Index" });
```

El segundo debió ser así

```
{variable-algo}/{controller=paquetes}/{variable-dos}
```

¿Alguien me podría orientar o alguna idea de como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno revisando y después de mucho revisar encontré la respuesta, lo anoto aquí por si alguien lo llegara a necesitar después.

Razor pages utiliza ConfigureServices para crear las rutas segun vi, y no yendonos a MapRoute como tal, entonces declaro o agrego AddPageRoute controlador y mi enlace amigable.

Así pude poner los quiones medios y tambien mandarle variables antes y despues de mi controlador como seria el de {destino}/pruebas/{servicio}

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //valida los enlaces para ponerlos en minisculas
        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Polices", "transportation-policy"))
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/privacy_notice", "privacy-notice"))
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/prueba", "{destino}/pruebas/{servicio}"))
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/QuoteTransfer", "{afiliado}/transfers/quote"));
    }
```

en mi archivo.cshtml.cs declaro mis dos variables

```
    public void OnGet(string destino, string servicio)
    {
        Message = string.Format("recupere {0} destino y servicio {1}",destino, servicio);
    }
```

y para finalizar tambien esta en mi @page, archivo.cshtml

```
@page "{destino}/{servicio}"
@model PruebaModel
```